# mLab doesn't return users

Tags: android, parse-server, mlab

I'm using mLab as the backend database for 
a mobile application.
Since two weeks I've noticed that the database doesn't return to my 
application some of the users that I have registered as objects on the 
database. Initially all was working but all of a sudden this problem is 
appeared. I use on my application the Parse library to perform requests 
to the database and, when I perform a query for an application user, the 
Parse library raises the "com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Object not found." Exception, when, instead, the user exists on the database.

Is there something that I can do for solving this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Could you add more details of your problems? E.g codes of where you connect to mlab.

Double check that you are connecting to the right mlab DBURI.It seems like to me you are connected to the wrong mongoDB since you cant query the existing user.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Comment: The problem appears when I try to fetch a user that is stored as a refernce in anther object, that is when I make: parseObject.getUser().fetchIfNeeded(). At this point the library raises the "Object not found Exception", even if I have controlled that the references are all right! I have checked the reference to the DB and it is correct! Moreover, the strange thing is that this happens only for users for which I have performed a login in order to test the app, instead the users for which I have not performed a login they returns to my app correctly!

Comment: It seems like if the users that have performed a login are stored in a separate cache but then they are not returned when I perform a query, and I don't know if this happens at level of the Parse library or at the level of mLab and how to overcome this!